# React-hook-form useFieldArray for an array of strings instead of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongoose-schema, react-hook-form

I am using useFieldArray to fetch default values from my backend api. My **categories** is an array of strings. However, react-hook-form only supports array of objects. Here is my mongoose's schema

```
 type BookDocument = Document & {
  title: string
  description: string
  categories: string[]
  language: string
  publicationYear: number
}

const bookSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: [{ type: String, requried: true }],
    language: { type: String, required: true },
    publicationYear: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

Therefore, from the frontend I had to modify my form as follows:

```
type FormData = {
  title: string
  description: string
  categories: { category: string }[]
  language: string
  year: number
}

 const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    mode: 'onBlur',
    defaultValues: {
      title: book.title ?? '',
      description: book.description ?? '',
      categories:
        book.categories.map((elem) => {
          return { category: elem }
        }) ?? '',
      language: book.language ?? '',
      year: book.publicationYear ?? '',
    },
  })
```

The problem is when call the api request. The network payload will look like this and therefore can't be sent to the backend
[image]

Comment: Did you try to map through the categories and return just the values from each object in the backend? That way the array will match your mongoose schema

Comment: I am not sure how to do that because react-hook-form handle the values by its onSubmit form property and data is passed according to the declared type

Comment: can you give me more context about it? how are you handling the categories, are you using a checkbox for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `handleSubmit` function that you have deconstructed into a const (above your `control` in your snippet). You choose where to invoke that `handleSubmit` - likely on a button on your form - and instead of just invoking `handleSubmit`, you can invoke your callback, like so:

```
const handleFormSubmission = (data: any) => {
handleSubmit(wrappedSubmit)(data);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Check out the code I used to trick it to return flat array:

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Grid,
  InputLabel,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
import { Controller, useFieldArray, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

import InputErrorMessages from '../../../shared/InputErrorMessages';

export default function Variables() {
  const {
    control,
    formState: {
      errors,
    },
  } = useFormContext();
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    name: 'variables',
    control,
  });

  return(
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Typography variant="h6">Variables</Typography>
      <Box my={2}>
        <InputErrorMessages name="variables" errors={errors} />
      </Box>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        { fields.map((unused, index) => (
          <Grid item key={index} xs={12}>
            <Controller
              name={`variables.${index}`}
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <>
                  <InputLabel id="size">{`CRV${index+1} =`}</InputLabel>
                  <TextField 
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                    onBlur={field.onBlur}
                    inputRef={field.ref}
                    name={`variables.${index}.value`}
                    value={field.value.value || field.value}
                    sx={{ width: '100%' }}
                  />
                </>)}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <Grid item>
          <Button onClick={() => append('value')}>Add Variable</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          { fields.length > 0 && (<Button onClick={() => remove(fields.length - 1)}>Delete Variable</Button>)}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

I tricked it but not using the `field` item in the `fields.map`. Instead, I registered my own control using Controller because I want to control the name of the field and the value of it. Ie. I want to name the field `variables.${index}` instead of `variables.${index}.value`; the latter would be automatic if you used the `field` item returned by useFieldArray().

When you hit handleSubmit, you will see that the `variable` is a flat array.

However, there is a slight gotcha. If you load the form with fields from the backend, it will expect `variable` to be an array of objects with a `value` property; it won't understand a flat array of strings.

However, again, I was able to trick it because I control the value. Thus you see:

```
value={field.value.value || field.value}
```

Basically, if there is not `value` property on the object, then it must a string; so then just use the string.

Hope this helps!